# TCP Dup ACK after reconnection - sequence number problem?

Tags: networking, tcp, wireshark

currently I'm debugging the network traffic between two devices in the same network. The network architecture is quite simple.

Device 1 <-> Switch 1 <-> Switch 2 <-> Device 2

To verify the software on the devices, I check different scenarios.
One of them is the correct reconnection after I unplugged the network cable between Switch 1 and Switch 2 and plugged it in again after few seconds.

I uploaded a wireshark capture to my onedrive: [Wireshark capture](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuQ7D4UdXVKe3zJW68YVb2uxrJRK?e=7VbEJd)

Packets **1-9** are correct communication.

Between Packet **9** and Packet **10** the cable is unplugged.

In Packet **10** Device 1 tries to send data to Device 2 without receiving ACK.

In Packets **11/12** Device 2 sends Keep-Alive messages.

Between Packet **12** and **13** the cable is plugged in again.

Packet **13** ACKs the last Keep-Alive message, which seems fine.

From now on, it gets weird. I only see TCP Dup ACK messages.

I assume that the TCP stacks get confused on the difference in the sequence numbers.
While Device 1 thinks it's own sequence number is 49, Device 2 thinks it is 37.
Device 1 does not support Fast Retransmission.

Can someone explain what is happening here? I'm struggeling to understand where the problem is.
Is the problem in Device 1 where the TCP stack thinks it is on sequence number 49 while the package is not yet acknowledged or is it in Device 2?

I really appreciate your help.

Kindly,
Philipp

Comment: How are the layer 2 switches configured to deal with a disconnection and reconnection? If they have to run STP it can take a while.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_Tree_Protocol   It looks like neither is responding to the duplicate acks, which they should if they receive them; maybe they are not, though you do see both sides of the conversation.  How are you obtaining the network capture?

Comment: I don't know how they are configured. I'll investigate this.
It's an interesting thought, that they might not even receive the duplicate acks, even though they are captured.
There is a capturing computer connected to switch 2. Switch 2 mirrors the entire traffic to this port.

Comment: I assume you mean that you have spanned a port on switch 2, and that the port is the one connected to switch 1.  I'm not sure how a span works while STP is being run.  You might want to span the device 2 port on switch 2 and the device 1 port on switch 1 separately to see what each of them sees.